# How to prevent double calling of onChange callback in reactive form of Angular2+?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components, angular-reactive-forms

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svpg8g

I have some third part component (`ThirdPartCounter` in the `app/counter.component.ts`). I've wrapped it into the Angular component and subscribed on changing of this counter. When I interact with counter UI (`Increment` button) I have correct events in my stream. But! If I setup counter value manually (`Clear` button) I have duplicate of event in this stream (one is because component changing, next called after `writeValue`).

How should I prevent excess event after `writeValue` callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this , it will not duplicate with emitEvent  to false

```
 clear() {
  this.myForm.controls['counter'].patchValue(0, {emitEvent : false});
 }
```

check it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dc8cyl

Comment: `this.myForm.patchValue({counter: 0}, {emitEvent : false});` also works. Thanks!